# Finding all possible sequences of a given length from a given set in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose I have a set `S=["a", "b"]` and a number `L=2`. What function or standard library tool when passed S and L would yield `[["a","a"], ["a","b"], ["b","a"], ["b","b"]]` in no particular order?

I'm sure there's a simple answer, I've just been working on my program so long that my brain has been scrambled.

Comment: @relisher I was able to find my solution through that question, but calling it a duplicate is quite a stretch.

Comment: Not a stretch at all: a string is a sequence of characters, so without duplicates, can adequately represent a set of characters.

Comment: @user189728 while the question may not have been an exact duplicate, the answer to your question (in python!) is the accepted solution

Comment: @relisher fair enough, I guess I just took it as an attack, which is my fault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> [list(pair) for pair in itertools.product(S, repeat=2)]
[['a', 'a'], ['a', 'b'], ['b', 'a'], ['b', 'b']]
```